# Transform a function into something that lapply works on properly (lists)

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a list with 10 elements, each element consisting of 5 * i items drawn from a uniform distribution, i being the ith entry, and I want to use lapply.

Currently I made this function:

```
z_list <- list()
z_list_generator <- function(n) {
  for(i in 1:n){
  a <- runif(5 * i)
  tmp <- list(a)
  mybiglist[[i]] <- tmp
  }
  mybiglist
}
```

This function does give the correct outcome when I just put z_list_generator(2), it prints a list with the first element consisting of 5 elements, the second of 10 elements.

What I want to achieve is that I do lapply(some number, z_list_generator) such that it generates this same list, and such that when I do length(lapply(some number, z_list_generator)), the outcome is 'some number'.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
z_list_generator  <- function(k) lapply(1:k, function(i) runif(5 * i))

set.seed(2018)    # Fixed random seed for reproducibility
z_list_generator(2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.33615347 0.46372327 0.06058539 0.19743361 0.47431419
#
#[[2]]
# [1] 0.3010486 0.6067589 0.1300121 0.9586547 0.5468495 0.3956160 0.6645386
# [8] 0.9821123 0.6782154 0.8060278

length(z_list_generator(2))
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your z_list_generator is strange.
1) You do not initialise mybiglist in your function code. It probably modifies some global variable.
2) You assign mybiglist elements with another list (of lenght 1), which first element contains a sample from a uniform distrubution. Better assign a, not tmp there.